# Add switches to existing circuit

Tags: wiring, switch, light

[3 way switch 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIgmI.jpg)
[image: 3 way switch 2]
[image: existing lights controlled by 2 way switches]
[image: main electrical panel]

I currently have 5 lights controlled by two 3-way switches.

Not sure if this is relevant, but the above exists in a partially finished basement(Ceiling and two walls exist). I am completing the other two walls and will be running wires, adding outlets etc.

I intend to achieve the below configuration :

1. Make an existing 3 way switch to single pole that controls 2 lights
2. Make the second 3 way switch to single pole that controls 2 lights
3. Add a new switch(single pole) to control 1 light

Any ideas on how I can achieve the above configuration will be appreciated.
Can add any other relevant information that may be required.

Thank you

Comment: Post pictures of the existing 3-way switches showing all wires/cables. Do **not** disconnect anything.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes for the existing 3-way switches please?